# Protecting an IO pin from a spike

Tags: digital-logic, signal, uart, inductive

I am building a circuit which communicates with an external Power Supply via UART. One of the IO pins from my MCU is connected to an optocoupler[image: MCU pin to optocoupler]

I have 4 relays on my PCB, they are separated galvanically from the rest of the circuit, and powered from a separate power supply. The problem is, that I get a nasty spike on the UART line in the moment when one of the relays is operating. This is how it looks (measured in point TP4 on the schematic above):

[image: Oscillogram]

How can I prevent this spiking? I tried adding 2 clamping (Schottky) diodes to the supply rails, the problem still exists. I have a large GND polygon pour over the Bottom layer, even under the mentioned relays (not connected obviously), does it affect my circuit in any way?

EDIT:
This is the relay drive circuit:
[image]

Comment: Please show also the relay drive circuit.

Comment: Do you have problems with the UART itself when the scope probe is not connected? It is possible the **probe** picks up this spike: the scope image you show isn't necessary what the UART (without scope probe) sees.

Comment: Here is the relay circuit: https://imgur.com/a/ucaFOrX
Also, the problem persists even with the probe is disconnected

Comment: Is there anything connected to J11 to J14? If so, disconnect them to see whether the problem occurs by energising the relays or by switching the load connected to J11 to J14 (I assume the spike occurs due to load switching)

Comment: @Huisman yes, that was the issue! Thank You for the help. I was switching some electro valves, and it turns out that I (somehow) forgot the flyback diodes on their coils.

Comment: @MarekAnt: You should probably add an answer yourself, or delete the question if you think that it is unlikely (potentially too specific) to help anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

I was switching some electro valves, and it turns out that I (somehow) forgot the flyback diodes on their coils. The massive spike came from a separate circuit, but it was enough to mess with my circuitry.